# How to send alternate out of office message to all email belongs to a certain domain?

Tags: lotus-notes

I would like to setup my Lotus Notes (ver. 8.5.2) out of office so that it answer with an alternative message only to email addresses that contain a specific domain/site name (e.g. @gmail.com). Is it possible?

Comment: You didn't mention what version you're using. Can't you set a rule within out of office, or at least a rule as they come in?

Comment: I updated the question, version is 8.5.2

Answer (score 0):

I don't run lotus notes but [documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.notes85.help.doc%2Fmail_ooo_t.html) suggests-

> 1. Above message list click more - out of office
> 2. specify dates
> 3. optional - Send a different notification to certain people or domains
>
>    - Click Alternate Notification
>    - Specify one or more people or domains in the To field. To select names from a directory, click To.
>    - Edit the rest of the notification.

It says valid for 8.5 and 8.5.1, but it's in the directory including 8.5.2